# Check if files with absolute and relative path exists

Tags: php, path

Is there a way to check whether files (with either an absolute or relative path) exists? Im using PHP. I found a couple of method but either they only accept absolute or relative but not both. Thanks.

Comment: i forgot to mention what the logic for this is, if a file does not exist in the document root check from a remote url for a substitute. I think ill try Rob's answer. thanks guys

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`file_exists($file);` does the trick for both relative and absolute paths.

What's more useful, however, is having absolute paths without hardcoding it. The best way to do that is use `dirname(__FILE__)` which gets the directory's full path of the current file in ether UNIX or Windows format. Then we can use [`realpath()`](https://www.php.net/realpath) which conveniently returns false if file does not exist. All you have to do then is specify a relative path from that file's directory and put it all together:

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/include.php';
if (realpath($path)) {
    include($path);
}
```

Comment: realpath() return the canonical path, so wipe out symbolic links. Is there a way to avoid this, and check the path is absolute even if not canonical?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`realpath`](http://php.net/realpath) to check if a file exists to the given path and retrieve the expanded path to that file:

```
$absPath = realpath($path);
if ($absPath === false) {
    // invalid path
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`file_exists($path)` will check absolute path or relative to the script location.   If you want to check relative to document root you could try `file_exists("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}path");`

If you want a function that will take both relative and absolute paths something like this should work (untested):

```
function check_file($path) {
    return ( file_exists($path) || file_exists("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}path") );
}
```