# php: check if path exists?

Tags: php, directory

I am setting a path variable with a query-string.

What is the easiest way to check if the path (always a directory) exists or not.

```
    if(isset($_GET['p'])) {
    define(PATH, $_GET['p']);
```

So now I have like mydomain.com?p=files/folder/sub and everything works fine, i'm reading the contents of the folder. However, I can pass along ?p=shit/whatever and i don't get a 404 or anything like that. the system reads a folder which does not even exist.

I don't even need a 404, but just want to print('does not exist!') or anything similar.

What is the best method to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if files with absolute and relative path exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730547/check-if-files-with-absolute-and-relative-path-exists)

Comment: **DON'T!** this cries for [RFI](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2007-A3) – use whitelists for such things

Comment: so how would you do that with whitelists?

Comment: Create a whitelist array and use in_array() to check if the value exists in the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

file_exists: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

is_dir: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

Answer (score 1):

If this is on your local machine you can use `file_exists()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

```
if (!file_exists($filename)) {
  //print your error
}
```