# php: path in querystring - best way to prevent hacks and bugs?

Tags: php, directory

hey guys,
i know it's not the best way of doing this but the whole thing is just a little project which doesn't need anything more difficult.

i'm passing directory names along with my url like domain.com?p=folder/subfolder/etc

i'm looking for the best way to check if the dir exists and i want to (at least) kind of prevent people from going up in hierarchy.

now what i'm doing right now (almost) works, however i think there's a much better and easier and shorter way for that:

```
    if(isset($_GET['p'])) {
    if (realpath($_GET['p'])) {
        if (substr(PATH, 0, 1) == "" || substr(PATH, 0, 1) == "/" || substr(PATH, 0, 2) == "./" || substr(PATH, 0, 3) == "../") {
            print "directory is forbidden!";
        } else {
            define(PATH, $_GET['p']); 
        }
    } else {
        print "directory does not exist!";
    }
} else { define(PATH, "root"); }
```

what would you do?

Comment: Haven't read the link that @knittl posted in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981902/php-check-if-path-exists) ?

Comment: Your code just doesn't work. 

Which value has `PATH` when you do all your `substr()` tests ?

Seems that is is a constant defined before... Then, any subsequent calls to `define()` will have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should be mapping user input to a predetermined list of valid file names rather than allowing arbitrary paths to be used.**

Having said that, if you're just experimenting on a personal development machine, you can prepend any user submitted path with a path to an allowed base directory to help prevent system traversal. In addition, disallow any submitted paths that contain `./`, `../` or `~/`(not just at the beginning of the string, but anywhere).

You can use [preg_match](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) for this.

```
if (preg_match('#(\./|\.\./|~/|\\\)#', $_GET['p'])) {
    // disallow
}
```

Again, this is just for experimental development purposes. With any code intended for real use, you should map input to a predetermined list of valid paths.

Also, the logic of your code is flawed. `PATH` is never set before its first use, and even if you do set it `realpath` is used which escapes the traveral characters rendering the `substr` checks ineffective, and you're using a define where a variable is much more appropriate.