# Check file exist or not in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to check the file exist or not and display a defined image. I try to use the code as below. It always display the no.png only even the 1111.pdf is exist!

```
$fileUrl = "http://localhost/Report/1111.pdf";
 $AgetHeaders = @get_headers($sourcePath);
 if (preg_match("|200|", $AgetHeaders[0])) {
 // file exists
echo "<img src='http://localhost/Report/yes.png'>";
 } else {
 // file doesn't exists
echo "<img src='http://localhost/Report/no.png'>";
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try googling it?

[file_exists function](https://www.php.net/file_exists)

> ## file_exists
>
> file_exists — Checks whether a file or directory exists
>
> bool file_exists ( string $filename )

Example:

```
<?php
$filename = '/path/to/foo.txt';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
?>
```

Comment: Why it's not work for my server! `<?php
$file = 'http://localhost/Report/1.pdf';
if(file_exists($file))
{
echo "<img src='http://localhost/Report/yes.png'>";
}else{
echo "<img src='http://localhost/Report/no.png'>";
}`

Comment: What do you mean by "not work"? It gives an error? something?

Comment: The code just display the "no.png" even the file "1.pdf' is exist! and no error!

Comment: Try using relative paths instead of absolute paths.

Comment: relative path is work! how can I use the absolute path?

Comment: Do you have javascript script for doing same thing?

Comment: I suggest not working with hardcoded absolute paths. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730547/check-if-files-with-absolute-and-relative-path-exists) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function:-

```
if (file_exists('filename')) {
 …do something
 }
```

Comment: Why it's not work for my server! `<?php
$file = 'http://localhost/Report/1.pdf';
if(file_exists($file))
{
echo "<img src='http://localhost/Report/yes.png'>";
}else{
echo "<img src='http://localhost/Report/no.png'>";
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this function if you want to check external file

```
function curl_check_file_exist($url)
{
     $rarr = array();
    $useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRF91) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); //set our user agent
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);

   $header = substr($result, 0, $header_size);
   $result = substr($result, $header_size);
   $ok = $info['http_code'];


   if($ok == 200)
   {
     return true;
   }
   else
   {
    return false;
  }
 }
```

like this

```
 if(curl_check_file_exist($url))
 {
    .....

 }
 else
 {
    .....
 }
```

But i you want to check local file

```
file_exists(path)
```

function is good